# ng-repeat中に前の要素と比較して表示の出し分けをしたい２

Tags: monaca, angularjs

[ng-repeat中に前の要素と比較して表示の出し分けをしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9968/ng-repeat%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%81%A8%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97%E5%88%86%E3%81%91%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)
この質問と似たようなことで、日にちが変わったら（例:6/9から6/10へと日付を跨いだ時）リストに仕切りを入れたいのですが、うまくいかないのでアドバイスをどなたかお願いします。
上の回答では、

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{items[$index-1].created_at === item.created_at ? '\u00A0' : item.created_at}}</div>
    <div>{{item.item_id}}</div>
</div>
```

というように書けばいいと書いてありました。そこで、

```
<ons-row class="shikiri" ng-if="results[$index-1].attributes.updateDate|date:"MM/dd" !== 
result.attributes.updateDate|date:"MM/dd"">
```

とng-ifで、日付を比較するような条件を上の回答を参考に書いたのですが、`|date:"MM/dd"`
がエラーのようです。
nifty mbaasからのオブジェクトなので、.attributes.updateDateとして日付を取得しています。
（日付データは2015-06-10T15:15:48.754Zというような形式になっています。）

Answer (score 1):

ng-ifを"で開始しているので、MM/ddは『”』でなく『'』で囲んでください。
これだけで良さそうですが、なぜか結果をtoStringしないと正しく動きませんでした。

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('mainController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
  var a = new Date(2015,5,9,12,0)
  
  $scope.items = [
    {
      "item_id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2015-06-10T15:15:48.754Z"
    },
    {
      "item_id": 2,
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2015-06-10T10:15:48.754Z"
    },
    {
      "item_id": 3,
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2015-06-09T15:15:48.754Z"
    },
    {
      "item_id": 4,
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2015-06-09T10:15:48.754Z"
    },
    {
      "item_id": 5,
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2015-06-09T05:15:48.754Z"
    }
  ];
}
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <hr ng-if="$index != 0 && (items[$index-1].created_at|date:'MM/dd':'UTC').toString() !== (item.created_at|date:'MM/dd':'UTC').toString()">
        <div>{{item.item_id}}</div>
        <div>pre:{{items[$index-1].created_at|date:'MM/dd':'UTC'}}</div>
        <div>cur:{{item.created_at|date:'MM/dd':'UTC'}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！toStringを使うんですね！無事実行可能でした

Comment: ちょっと長い(100件くらい)repeatでテストしてみたら、たまに日付が変わっていないのに仕切りが追加されているようです。
:'UTC'を消したらエラーが消えました。